# What is the difference between StatefulSet and Deployment with respect to Volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-deployment

So yes, `StatefulSet` helps preserve the order and name of the pod, but what is it that it does extra (or different) that is advantageous over a regular `Deployment` with respect to volumes.

I see many examples of master/slave setup for databases as a use case for `StatefulSet`, but can't that problem be solved with just a `Deployment` (replicas=1) for the master and a `Deployment` (replicas=`<multiple>`) for the slaves. For volumes just create a `PV`/`PVC`.

Can someone please let me know what is the difference with respect to volumes?

Answer (score 1):

> So yes, StatefulSet helps preserve the order and name of the pod, but what is it that it does extra (or different) that is advantageous over a regular Deployment with respect to volumes.

With a **StatefulSet** each Pod get its own PersistentVolumeClaim, but with **Deployment** all Pods use the same PersistentVolumeClaim.

`StatefulSet` has `volumeClaimTemplates` that creates volumes for you from the template and it adds `-<ordinal>` on the name for PersistentVolumeClaims, so a name with `my-pvc` will be `my-pvc-0` and `my-pvc-1` if the StatefulSet has `replicas: 2`.

> I see many examples of master/slave setup for databases as a use case for StatefulSet, but can't that problem be solved with just a Deployment (replicas=1) for the master and a Deployment (replicas=) for the slaves. For volumes just create a PV/PVC.

Yes, that would probably work - for testing and development. But it would not be recommended in a production environment. Typically in a cloud (and Kubernetes) environment, you use a Database that use three replicas and that has an instance in every *Availability Zone* - this is easier to manage with a single `StatefulSet` with `replicas: 3` and proper PodAffinity configuration.